# How large can worker pools and job batches be in Golang?

Tags: go, worker-pool

I see so many guides or posts on *how* to implement worker pools in Go, but I am having a hard time understanding how much this can scale.

Would it be alright to have a pool of 50 workers, create a slice of 1 million jobs and just run the worker pool on all of the jobs? Or is it better to divide the jobs into smaller batches and start a new worker pool for each batch of jobs? The context of the jobs is just performing one get request per job and writing some stuff from the result to a database.
Right now I have 50 workers for millions of jobs and I had a problem with the file descriptor limits, now increased the limit. I want to improve my script/configuration so that my worker pool - http get requests are faster. I need some intuition of what I need to do.

Comment: If you hit a file descriptor limit with only 50 workers, the number of workers is probably not the issue. It sounds like you have another bug causing a resource leak.

Comment: You have multiple things to consider. 50 workers are quite low. Database connection limits? If you're issuing get request, maybe bandwidth? If you're calling the same API, maybe rate limiting? Figure out what is limiting, then tune it by trying different worker pool sizes. This, of course, assuming your worker pool implementation is correct.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I use io.ReadAll to read the response body. When I hit the file descriptor limit, my ulimit -n was 1024. Then I increased it to 4096 which helped for some time, but eventually hit the limit again. I am sharing a single http client among my workers, closing the response body after i read it (also tried to do it with defer, no difference), and even setting its close header to true.

One possible issue: I send a get request, if there is an error I send another. Should I close the body of the first one even though there was an error with the request and I don't process it?

Comment: @BurakSerdar I use [this pattern](https://itnext.io/explain-to-me-go-concurrency-worker-pool-pattern-like-im-five-e5f1be71e2b0) for my worker pool. I do not write to my database from my workers, I write after they return their results to my main program in a single line. I need to perform the get requests really fast, handling 1m requests in a few hours. I am using a 8GB ram with 4vCPU droplet from digitalocean, but will deploy to a stronger server once I figure things out.

Comment: From the overview of [`net/http`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http): "The client must close the response body when finished with it". Are you doing that?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco yes of course. I was doing it with defer, but now I am closing it myself (because maybe it's more efficient to close it as soon as possible?).

Comment: You have something else going on. 50 is too few.

Comment: The problem with my code was not closing the body when the get request returns with an error. This caused a memory leak and a leak with the file descriptors as well. Closing bodies solved that problem.